# how can I set text between left and center in a TextView in Android, is there any way I can use margin for the text?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I put the texts in my white-colored textviews in Android in same location like those in my another pic? if I use android:gravity="left|center", it will be in the left-corner in the center, but I dont want it to be 100% left, what to do? is there any margin-type code for text in textView? Any tips would be appreciated, thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `android:paddingLeft` attribute to add some space in your text view.